# Doc string facility in C++

Tags: c++, c, documentation

Languages like Python, MATLAB, E-Lisp have this nice facility for  doc-strings. 
With this feature using just a few keystrokes in the terminal,  you can fetch the documentations of the functions / module you have written and imported into your code.

Now is there any "technique" (library, Editor tricks , whatever to )  to get a similar facility in 
C++ / C. Suppose I include the documentation of the function within the source file at
the head of the function, 
then I would like to type a command like getinfo  at the terminal. (something
like a man page)

I know such a 'man' facility exists for many C functions, but the documentation for these functions are written in separate text files from the source code. I would like the
documentation to be in-place

Comment: Yes, but with Doxygen, I dont think one can extract the documentation from the terminal. I would like a terminal based facility. With Doxygen I need to open the documentation in a web-browser. Or maybe Doxygen has this facility already?

Comment: Doxygen [can generate manpages](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/starting.html#man_out).

Comment: I even put that as an answer, whoa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It has support for generating [man pages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#man_output), among other formats.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio can/will generate popups containing information extracted from [DocXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177227) formatted comments. You have to compile with [`/doc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501), which will extract the XML from the comments to a `.xdc` file. Then you have to run [`xdcmake`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177247) to compile the `.xdc` files into an xml file. You'd typically handle all this automatically in the build process, so you don't have to do much manually (except write the comments themselves, of course). The one thing to keep in mind, however, is that the code (at least a declaration) has to build before you get the popups.

I feel obliged to add that IMO, most such comments are generally pretty close to useless. If a corporate standard makes them unavoidable, so be it -- but if they're honestly providing any useful information, I'd consider that an indication of a problem ("Code smell", if you prefer that wording). In most cases, the combination of the name of the function (or whatever) and the names/types of the parameters *should* make the use of the function quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you notate your code with comments in a syntax similar to Javadoc, you can generate a documentation for your code, in various different formats, using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It can generate, among other things, man pages, but it seems that the preferred output format people use is HTML pages.